# Is benzoyl peroxide discredited?

Tags: treatment-options

For years I was able to get three main kinds of acne treatment creams: salicylic acid, benzoyl peroxide, and random herbal extracts of questionably effectiveness.

Earlier this year, the benzoyl peroxide options started disappearing off the shelves. Now I can't find one anywhere. (I'm in Ontario, Canada.)

What gives? Is it no longer considered useful or something?

Comment: This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. Have you tried simply googling the question? For the last two years there have been shortages of all sorts of common things due the the pandemic. I can't find saltine crackers, foam insulation, a hair product my wife likes, and a half dozen other common items. Have you considered that possibility?

Comment: @CareyGregory Hmm. Looks like [there are some ongoing shortages](https://www.drugshortagescanada.ca/ingredient/500?orderby=created_date&order=desc&shortage_page=1&limit=20&discontinuance_limit=10&shortage_limit=10&allow_all_user_shortages=1).

Comment: Then perhaps you would care to answer your own question?